Understanding Phase Maps and Dephasing in a Periodically Driven Qubit System
I am working on a periodically driven qubit system and trying to understand the concepts of phase maps and dephasing. Here is the setup:
The initial qubit state is given by:
$\cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle+\sin(\theta/2)e^{i\varphi}|1\rangle$
The Hamiltonian for the system is:
$H=H_0+H_t$
where T is period,and,
$H_0=\alpha \sigma_z$ $H_t=\cos(\varphi)*\delta(t-nT)$
I can calculate the state evolution over time and visualize it on the Bloch sphere. However, I am struggling to understand:

What exactly is a phase map in this context?
How can I extract or identify dephasing effects from my results? Like by adding $\sigma_x$? Or anything else?

Any insights or references to similar systems would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

can you include a source talking about a "phase map"? What's the context?
